# VBA on powerpoint: how to make a variable to make it able to used on every slides?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

So on Office 2013 Powerpoint, I'm trying to make a Jeopardy game...
I'm going to create buttons on each ANSWER slides.
What this button will do is: Set a variable "Amount" to according amount of money the question is worth. After that, it changes the slide to the SCORING slide.

Here is the question...
How do you make it, so the variable "Amount" (whether it's 100, 200, etc.) to be used on the SCORING slide?
I think I'm suppose to use PUBLIC somehow, but I'm a newbie and I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

At the top of any module in the project do

```
Public lAmount as Long
```

The value of the variable will be available to all modules in the project.  You might want to dim the variable as some other type, but for Jeopardy, Long will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to this question, it should help you out. If you're still stuck after that, let me know.

[Setting Global Variables in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241167/setting-global-variables-in-vba)